# How do I query a null date inside an array in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In an elasticsearch query I am trying to search Document objects that have an array of approval notifications. The notifications are considered complete when `dateCompleted` is populated with a date, and considered pending when either `dateCompleted` doesn't exist or exists with `null`. If the document does not contain an array of approval notifications then it is out of the scope of the search.

I am aware of putting `null_value` for field `dateCompleted` and setting it to some arbitrary old date but that seems hackish to me.

I've tried to use Bool queries with `must exist doc.approvalNotifications and must not exist doc.approvalNotifications.dateCompleted` but that does not work if a document contains a mix of complete and pending approvalNotifications. e.g. it only returns document with ID 2 below. I am expecting documents with IDs 1 and 2 to be found.

How can I find pending approval notifications using elasticsearch?

**PUT my_index/_mapping/Document**

```
 "properties" : {
  "doc" : {
    "properties" : {
      "approvalNotifications" : {
        "properties" : {
          "approvalBatchId" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "approvalTransitionState" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "approvedByUser" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : {
                "type" : "keyword",
                "ignore_above" : 256
              }
            }
          },
          "dateCompleted" : {
            "type" : "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Documents:**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "Pending Notifications",
    "approvalNotifications": [
        {
            "approvalBatchId": "e6c39194-5475-4168-9729-8ddcf46cf9ab",
            "dateCompleted": "2018-11-15T16:09:15.346+0000"
        },
        {
            "approvalBatchId": "05eaeb5d-d802-4a28-b699-5e593a59d445",
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 2,
    "status": "Pending Notifications",
    "approvalNotifications": [
        {
            "approvalBatchId": "e6c39194-5475-4168-9729-8ddcf46cf9ab",
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 3,
    "status": "Complete",
    "approvalNotifications": [
        {
            "approvalBatchId": "e6c39194-5475-4168-9729-8ddcf46cf9ab",
            "dateCompleted": "2018-11-15T16:09:15.346+0000"
        },
        {
            "approvalBatchId": "05eaeb5d-d802-4a28-b699-5e593a59d445",
            "dateCompleted": "2018-11-16T16:09:15.346+0000"            
        }
    ]
}

{
    "id": 4
    "status": "No Notifications"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, you can achieve the desired behavior by using [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/nested.html) datatype for the `"approvalNotifications"` field.

What happens is that Elasticsearch flattens your `approvalNotifications` objects, treating their subfields as subfields of the original document. The [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/nested.html) field instead will tell ES to index each inner object as an implicit separate object, though related to the original one.

To query `nested` objects one should use [`nested` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can try that. It seems that I need to re-create the entire index as changing a type to nested in the `/my_index/_mapping` API isn't allowed.

Comment: @dukthrash Yes, unfortunately the reindexing is necessary.